# How to randomly append "Yes/No" (ratio of 7:3) to a column in pandas dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe , which consists of three columns. And i want to append "Yes" or "No" to one of the column using python-pandas. Also the ratio between Yes:No is 7:3.

Had anyone tried this??

Comment: Will the length of the column always be a multiple of 10?

Comment: Yes, It has 2480500 rows × 3 columns

Comment: What does "append to a column" mean?  Do you have a text column, like `["A","B","C"]`, and you want `["AYes", "BNo", "CYes"]`?  Or you you want to create a new column with values which are "Yes" or "No"?

Answer (score 9):

With numpy's [`random.choice`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-dev/reference/generated/numpy.random.choice.html):

```
df["new_column"] = np.random.choice(["Yes", "No"], len(df), p=[0.7, 0.3])
```

Note: np.random.choice consists of independent trials (unless you pass `replace = False`). In each trial, the probability of getting a "Yes" will be 0.7. In the end you might not end up exactly with a 70% ratio. However, with 2480500 rows this binomial distribution will approximate to a normal distribution with a mean `2480500 * 0.7` and a standard deviation `sqrt(2480500 * 0.7 * 0.3)`. With `+/-3 standard deviation` (with 99.73% probability) you will end up with a ratio between `(0.69913, 0.70087)`. But if you want exactly 70%, you can use pandas' sample as [@EdChum suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37331217/2285236), I guess it has a correction factor.

Comment: This is probably the fastest solution

Comment: @EdChum np.random.choice is quite fast in general but it has an issue when you pass `replace = False` https://github.com/numpy/numpy/issues/2764

Comment: Npte that this is slightly different from some of the other answers (like EdChum's), in that it gives each element a 70% chance of being Yes (and therefore there's a low but nonzero probability of being all No), whereas Ed's would always give 70% of the elements being Yes.  Without clarification from the OP it's hard to know which was intended.

Comment: This is my choice for best answer.  Very elegant.

Answer (score 3):

You can use [`sample`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.sample.html) to achieve this:

```
In [11]:
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(20,3), columns=list('abc'))
df

Out[11]:
           a         b         c
0  -0.267704  1.030417 -0.494542
1  -0.830801  0.421847  1.296952
2  -1.165387 -0.381976 -0.178988
3  -0.800799 -0.240998 -0.900573
4   0.855965  0.765313 -0.125862
5   1.153730  1.323783 -0.113135
6   0.242592 -2.137141 -0.230177
7  -0.451582  0.267415  1.006564
8   0.071916  0.476523  1.326859
9  -1.168084  0.250367 -1.235262
10  0.238183  0.391661 -1.177926
11 -1.153294 -0.304811 -0.955384
12 -0.984470 -0.351073 -1.155049
13 -2.068388  1.294905  0.892136
14 -0.196381 -1.083988  0.203369
15 -1.430208  0.859933  1.152462
16 -0.250452  0.824815  0.425096
17  1.051399 -1.199689  0.487980
18  0.688910 -0.664028 -0.097302
19 -0.355774  0.064857  0.003731

In [12]:    
df.loc[df.index.to_series().sample(frac=0.7).index, 'new_col'] = 'Yes'
df['new_col'].fillna('No',inplace=True)
df

Out[12]:
           a         b         c new_col
0  -0.267704  1.030417 -0.494542     Yes
1  -0.830801  0.421847  1.296952     Yes
2  -1.165387 -0.381976 -0.178988      No
3  -0.800799 -0.240998 -0.900573      No
4   0.855965  0.765313 -0.125862      No
5   1.153730  1.323783 -0.113135     Yes
6   0.242592 -2.137141 -0.230177     Yes
7  -0.451582  0.267415  1.006564     Yes
8   0.071916  0.476523  1.326859      No
9  -1.168084  0.250367 -1.235262     Yes
10  0.238183  0.391661 -1.177926     Yes
11 -1.153294 -0.304811 -0.955384     Yes
12 -0.984470 -0.351073 -1.155049     Yes
13 -2.068388  1.294905  0.892136     Yes
14 -0.196381 -1.083988  0.203369      No
15 -1.430208  0.859933  1.152462     Yes
16 -0.250452  0.824815  0.425096     Yes
17  1.051399 -1.199689  0.487980     Yes
18  0.688910 -0.664028 -0.097302     Yes
19 -0.355774  0.064857  0.003731      No
```

Basically you can call `sample` and pass param `frac=0.7` and then use the index to mask the df and assign the 'yes' value and then call `fillna` to assign the 'no' values

Answer (score 2):

```
import pandas as pd
import random

arr = ['Yes'] * 7 + ['No'] * 3
arr *= number_of_rows // 10

random.shuffle(arr)

df['column_name'] = arr
```

Answer (score 1):

## Quick and Dirty

```
pd.Series(np.random.rand(100)).apply(lambda x: 'Yes' if x < .7 else 'No')
```